# Переопределен ли метод equals для LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, equals

В интерфейсе List прописан метод equals, но в классе LinkedList я не нашел его. Но метод equals на LinkedList работает правильно, он сравнивает внутренность, а не ссылки. Значит все-таки переопределен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то вы ну очень плохо искали

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализацию можно посмотреть [здесь](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java#l512).